# How to prevent my "push" from putting everything in one array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have input fields, which are created based on my arrays in my JSON file.

However, when I insert something in my input fields, it goes right until I start inserting stuff in the input fields that aren't part of the other input fields. Don't worry, more explaining to come.

This is how my JSON looks like:

```
{
  "main_object": {
    "id": "5",
    "getExerciseTitle": "TestFor",
    "language": "nl_NL",
    "application": "lettergrepen",
    "main_object": {
      "title": "TestFor",
      "language": "nl_NL",
      "exercises": [{
          "word": "test",
          "syllables": [
            "test01",
            "test02",
            "test03",
            ""
          ]
        },
        {
          "word": "tesst",
          "syllables": [
            "test11",
            "test12",
            "",
            ""
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "dataType": "json"
  }
}
```

As you can see I have multiple arrays called `syllables`. What I am trying to do is: Create the `push` until it reaches the matched array in JSON, it should then change the input fields to buttons. However, when I go over to the next input fields that are linked to the second array, instead of starting the `push` from 0 it keeps on going.

A picture for you to see what I mean (note the `console.log()` too).

[image]

So: Instead of having the `push` start over it keeps on adding it to the already existing array. I want this NOT to happen so I can later on make a check that checks whether the `push` equals the array and then assign all the desired input fields to green buttons.

This is how my code looks like right now:

```
var x = [];

function prepareCheck() {
  $.getJSON('json_files/jsonData_' + ID + '.json', function(json) {
    $(document).on('change', '.syl-input', function() {
      var rowCounter = $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().attr('id');
      var inputCounter = $(this).attr('id');
      var jsyl = json.main_object.main_object.exercises[rowCounter].syllables[inputCounter];
      var jsylall = json.main_object.main_object.exercises[rowCounter].syllables;
      var valueInput = $(this).val();
      console.log(jsylall);
      if (valueInput == jsyl) {
        var correctInput = $('<input/>', {
          'class': 'form-control',
          'type': 'text',
          'id': 'button' + CBC++,
          'value': valueInput
        });
        console.log(jsyl);
        x.push(valueInput);

        if (valueInput == '') {
          x.remove($(this).val());
        };
        console.log(x);

        $(this).replaceWith(correctInput);
        S.playRight();
        S.addRight();
      } else if ($.inArray(valueInput, jsylall) >= -1) {
        $(this).css({
          'color': '#e00413'
        });
        S.playWrong();
        S.addWrong();
      }

    });
  });
}
```

Question: How can I reset `x.push` again? so I can keep on checking whether the input fields have the desired words/length to change them to green buttons?

Comment: You never create or use multiple arrays in the first place. You only have `x`. Where else is pushed stuff supposed to end up, if all you ever do is call `x.push(...)`?

Comment: That is correct. Maybe I should adjust what I meant: How can I make x.push() reset when it comes out of the desired array instead of having the words stack in x.push()?

Comment: I assume you're constructing the HTML form based on the json anyway, so why not put the correct syllable into a `data-syl` attribute for each input, then simply check for all inputs if their `.val()` matches `.data("syl")`?

Comment: The first part was correct, about the input fields etc. being created based on the JSON file. However I lost you at the correct syllable into a data-syl. Could you refer a link or elaborate on that?

Comment: You create `<input type="text" data-syl="test01">`, then for all inputs in a row, compare their `.val()` against `.data("syl")`

Comment: Well, apart from what you said is very valid to do so, I have to make the input fields to green buttons when they are all filled out correctly for each row. going by my picture above it would be: the first word has 3 input fields that should turn into green buttons when all the 3 are filled out correctly. This should also go for the second word with 2 input fields. If I do this with .data it will make them go green one by one.

Comment: @JJShow No, only if you write code that does that. If you write code that does what you want to happen instead, it'll work. How the comparison works is completely unrelated to whether the inputs are turned into buttons one by one or all at once. For each word, test all inputs. If all are matches, turn all of them green. Simple.

Comment: Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/eo2hz3vx/

Comment: Ah yes. That's exactly what I meant. I guess you were right after all and I was completely wrong lol. I hope you don't mind if I ask you this tho: I see people put the JSON files in functions etc. but how would a person actually append the content of a real JSON file to a function? Or can I write somehing like this and use the variable to just append? var jsyl = json.main_object.main_object.exercises[rowCounter].syllables[inputCounter] Thanks Chris. I will take a closer look at your code since that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I just put it in a function for the purposes of the demonstration, and to be able to move it to the bottom of the script. Doing this in your case is completely pointless. If the JSON file is external, just load it with `$.getJSON()`, like you did.